# iOS update CALayer in UIView animation block

Tags: ios, autolayout, calayer, uiviewanimation

So i have the following function

```
- (void)setMoreMenuHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void(^)(BOOL))completion
{
    if (!hidden)
    {
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^
         {
             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
             [_profileInfoVC viewWillLayoutSubviews];
         }];
    }
}
```

and within `_profileInfoVC` i have it doing

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    self.pictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.pictureImageView.frame.size.width/2;
    self.pictureImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

So i am aware that layers are ignored within the animation blocks but I assume this also means updating at all since it remains quite square during and after the animation. Is there a solution to this that does not require me also creating a Core Animation for just the layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the block you are interested in this regard is the Completion block.

```
- (void)setMoreMenuHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void(^)(BOOL))completion
{
    if (!hidden)
    {
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^
         {
             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             [_profileInfoVC viewWillLayoutSubviews];
         }];
    }
}
```

the above seems to have fixed my issue, also i was never really a fan of directly calling `viewWillLayoutSubviews` directly so that line has been changed to `[_profileInfoVC.view setNeedsLayout];`